# BibTeX can't open style file

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I have a problem making my bibliography run. I had the same code some time ago and it did run then, I can't figure out what the problem is.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[comma,authoryear]{natbib}
\begin{document}
Blablabla \cite{xy}
\bibliographystyle{natbib}
\bibliography{rp_bib.bib}
\end{document}
```

When I run LaTeX and afterwards BibTeX, it says `I couldn't open style file natbib.bst
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command 
I couldn't open database file...`

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you. A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code. Alternatively, use the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: As far as I know there is no standard `natbib.bst` file. The standard ones are `abbrvnat`, `plainnat` and `unsrtnat`.

Answer (score 18):

There are several errors in your MWE. I have corrected them and included a short example `bib` file with package `filecontents` (for the manual type `texdoc filecontents` in your command line).

Please have a look for the bibliography style: `natbib` is the name of the package, you ment `natdin` I guess. Macro `\bibname` needs only the name (here: `\jobname`) of your bib file. Leave out `.bib` (Explanation: If you store the MWE with the file name `mwe.tex` your created `bib` file will be named `mwe.bib`).

Corrected and pretty printed MWE:

```
%http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85424/bibtex-cant-open-style-file
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}  % writes bib file.
@book{adams,
  title     = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author    = {Douglas Adams},
  series    = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year      = {1980},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[comma,authoryear]{natbib}
%\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
Blablabla \cite{adams}
\bibliographystyle{natdin} % natdin alphadin
\bibliography{\jobname}    % use file \jobname.bib for bibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, now everything is running just fine.

Comment: @Franziska: You are welcome. Please consider to upvote and accept my answer if it was helpful for you. That's the way we say here thank you.